# StackOverflow's RentACoder Service

Tags: discussion, jobs

It just occured to me that SO can be a place that connects software buyers and sellers. You see, we have SO careers that matches employers with employees. But what about something more short term? Or something freelancing?

SO's RenACoder (Yes, the omission of T *is* deliberate) would surely beats the real [RentACoder](http://www.rentacoder.com/), for sure.

Comment: So cheap it can't even afford that extra T?

Comment: Maybe it's an attempt to make a distinctive tradmark. Unfortunately, trademark law says that simple mispellings don't confer distinctiveness

Comment: This would be vastly more useful to me than Careers...  I would love to hire developers with a high rep.  Especially since reading their SO posts would be a great way to determine if the developer is a good writer and clear communicator!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/freelance-jobs-in-sof - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29008/how-do-you-respond-when-someone-offers-to-pay-you-on-so

Comment: >So cheap it can't even afford that extra T?
Haha, I was about to make the spelling correction, and I thought that it would be better to just let it be as it is.

Answer (score 3):

"Careers" doesn't necessarily *have* to be for permanent-employment inquiries. It could just as easily be used for temporary, contract, or single-assignment projects. But the central idea is that "careers" breaks from tradition by allowing employers to seek out qualified employees and not the other way around.

As far as for-rent coders bidding on assignments placed by would-be contractees, I don't see how StackOverflow adds anything special to that dynamic... I don't see it as a good fit.

Comment: I agree with Robert, if this is what you're looking for (either as a contractor/employee, or as a company/employer) then go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com and get busy!

Answer (score 0):

Jeff didn't seem to have a very warm and fuzzy opinion about sites like RentACoder [last year](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001190.html).

If someone could get it right, I think it may be him.

There are a lot of issues that would have to be figured out to make it work well.